# Changing the state of class component from a functional component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I currently have a class component and a functional component in my Main component

Below is the code snippet for the:

**The Class component**

```
class ComponentForm extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            modal: true
        }
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
toggle() {
    this.setState({
        modal: !this.state.modal
    })
}
handleSubmit(values){
    console.log('Current State is: ' + JSON.stringify(values));
    alert('Current State is: ' + JSON.stringify(values));
}
    render(){
        return(
            <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle}>

               . . . .  

            </Modal>
        )
    }
}
```

**Functional Component**

```
function RenderComments({ comments }) {
    return (
        <>
        {
            . . . .
        )}
            <div>
                <Button type="submit" value="submit"}>
                    <i className="fa fa-pencil"></i> Submit Comment</Button>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

So what I want to do is to change the state of the class component from the functional component by the onClick action of the button. How can I accomplish the task?

Comment: Could you please provide the part of the code where you're mounting the `RenderComments` component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a function to update the state from your `ComponentForm` to `RenderComments` as a prop, then use it in the Button as onClick

for instance, you can pass the `toggle()` function (if that's what you want to achieve at the children, then in your `RenderComments`:

```
function RenderComments({ comments, toggle }) {
    return (
        <>
        {
            . . . .
        )}
            <div>
                <Button type="submit" value="submit" onClick={toggle}>
                    <i className="fa fa-pencil"></i> Submit Comment</Button>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `toggle` method to the functional component via props, and add it to an onClick for example, and that will do the job